# How to detect if submenu is shown?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, submenu, popupmenu

In Delphi XE2, how can I detect if a submenu is shown from a popup menu?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have modified the question, so now it contains only one question. However, the second question was not really a second question, but a sub-question of the first question. Thanks.  
I am trying to show tooltips for popup menu items and trying to avoid collisions between the tooltip and popup menu or popup menu submenu respectively, especially when the popup menu is near a screen border.

Comment: It might have  been better to ask about the problem rather than ask about your solution. Normally menu hints are shown in a status bar.

Comment: Yes. But this window does not have a status bar as it is not a normal window.

Answer (score 1):

When a sub-menu is shown, its parent menu item's OnClick event is fired.

Comment: But when the submenu hides it is not anymore shown. So the event told me that the submenu popped up and now my program thinks the submenu is still shown even if it is actually hidden. - Mmh, this may be a misunderstanding: Do you understand "shown" as being visible or as an event?

Comment: Shown indicates an event. Showing indicates a state. You asked for the former.

Comment: Anyway, if you want my advice you should ask about your root problem. Asking about your solution leads to answers like this. Answers that are pedantically accurate but no use to you whatsoever.